# CakePHP 1.2 cake i18n extract, generate files based on token/domain

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I'm using CakePHP 1.2. I have defined all the strings for which I need localization in gettext function. e.g.

file app/views/posts/add.thtml

```
<?php echo __("Text1.","feature_one"); ?>
<?php echo __("Text2.","feature_two"); ?>
```

file app/views/posts/edit.thtml

```
<?php echo __("Text3.","feature_one"); ?>
<?php echo __("Text4.","feature_two"); ?>
```

While generating the pot files, I'm using the cake i18n extract command from the cake console folder

```
cake i18n extract
```

Using this command I'm able to extract pot files in 2 formats, one in which all the strings are extracted and merged to one single file say 'default.pot', or all the strings are extracted to independent files with file names as the relative file path e.g. "-posts-add.pot" & "-posts-edit.pot".

What I need is to generate pot files based on the tokens/domains defined in the gettext function. i.e. one file each for a token/domain defined containing all the strings in that domain. e.g. "feature_one.pot" & "feature_two.pot".

Answer (score 1):

Use __d() instead of __(). [See the manual.](http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Internationalization-Localization.html#internationalizing-your-application)

This should extract them to a file named after the first arg. I haven't used 1.2 for years but the function still exists in 3.0 and I think it never changed.

Comment: tried with the same command "cake i18n extract", with both merge all files yes & no options, still i am not getting files with domain wise